# No entra en la sentencia if, dentro del While

Tags: php, mysqli

Sucede lo siguiente, estoy haciendo un update, al ingresar una factura de los proveedores, y al hacer click en un boton x se ejecuta una función(la colocare mas abajo) funciona bien, se actualiza el stock de los productos ingresados con la factura de la sucursal a la que se le ingreso, pero ¿ Que sucede si no existe ese producto en esa sucursal? bueno, hice un if que comprobara que si no arroja un resultado, se insertaran los productos en la sucursal, y si existieran, que se actualizara el stock de cada uno, pero no funciona, creo que el if esta mal. Les dejo mi función (igual es larga... PD: la tabla es porque solamente copie el while que tenia pra q se mostraran los productos.) :

```
  <?php 

   function ingresar_stock()

          {//consulta

            $id_if=$this->id_if;
            $id_di="";

    $sql="SELECT detalle_ingreso.id_di, detalle_ingreso.cantidad, detalle_ingreso.costo, productos.nombre_producto, 
            marcas.nombre_marca, ingreso_factura.id_if,ingreso_factura.id_suc, detalle_ingreso.codigo_producto, productos.precio_costo 
            FROM detalle_ingreso 
            INNER JOIN productos ON detalle_ingreso.codigo_producto = productos.codigo_producto
            INNER JOIN ingreso_factura ON detalle_ingreso.id_if = ingreso_factura.id_if 
            INNER JOIN marcas ON productos.id_marca = marcas.id_marca WHERE detalle_ingreso.id_if='$id_if'"; 

    $resultado=mysqli_query($this->conexion,$sql);
    $tabla="";


    while ($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))

    {               $codigo_producto=$datos["codigo_producto"];
                    $nombre_producto=$datos["nombre_producto"];
                    $nombre_marca=$datos["nombre_marca"];
                    $precio_costo=$datos["precio_costo"];
                    $cantidad=$datos["cantidad"];
                    $costo=$datos["costo"];
                    $id_di=$datos["id_di"];
                    $id_suc=$datos["id_suc"];

        $tabla.="<tr>

                    <td style='width: 15px; text-align: center'>$codigo_producto</td>
                    <td style='width: 190px; text-align: center'>$nombre_producto</td>
                    <td style='width: 20px; text-align: center'>$nombre_marca</td>
                    <td style='width: 20px; text-align: center'>$precio_costo</td>
                    <td style='width: 20px; text-align: center'>$cantidad</td>
                    <td style='width: 20px; text-align: center'>$costo</td>
                    <td style='width: 20px; text-align: center'><button    id_di='$id_di' class='btn btn-sm btn-default eliminar' >Eliminar<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button></td>
                </tr>         <div class='col-md-2' style='top: 25px;'>";

            //--- Mi consulta, para verificar que no existe el producto en esa sucursal
            $sql_con="SELECT productos.codigo_producto , sucursales.id_suc
             FROM productos_sucursales
             INNER JOIN productos ON productos_sucursales.codigo_producto=productos.codigo_producto
             INNER JOIN sucursales ON productos_sucursales.id_suc=sucursales.id_suc
             WHERE productos_sucursales.id_suc='$id_suc' AND productos_sucursales.codigo_producto='$codigo_producto'";       
             $resultado_con=mysqli_query($this->conexion,$sql_con); 

             if($resultado_con==0){

                 $sql_insert="INSERT INTO productos_sucursales values('','$id_suc','$codigo_producto','$cantidad')";
         $resultado_insert=mysqli_query($this->conexion,$sql_insert);


             }

             else{

                 $sql2="UPDATE productos_sucursales
            SET stock_real=stock_real  + $cantidad
            WHERE codigo_producto=$codigo_producto AND id_suc=$id_suc";
        $resultado2=mysqli_query($this->conexion,$sql2);


              }



    }
    return $tabla;
}

   ?>
```

Comment: tienes que tener cuiadado con las comilas... `id_suc ` y `codigo_producto` son de tipo integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes dejar tu if

```
if(!$resultado_con){

}
```

Ya que devuelve `false` en caso de no encontrar resultados.

Mi respuesta es similar a la de @Error404, solo que la mia se ahorra la evaluacion de `== false` ya que `if` evalua resultados booleanos por lo tanto si evaluas `!$resultado_con` estas buscando el resultado en caso de que sea `false` (vacio) si no, y trae un `object` que es el resultado en caso que tu query corresponda caera en la sentencia `else`

**EDICION**

Prueba asi :

```
$rows = $resultado_con->num_rows;
if($rows == 0){
       //insert
}
```

Comment: pero si lo dejo asi se duplica el producto

Comment: Que te devuelve $resultado_con cuando lo imprimes?

Comment: no devuelve nada...

Comment: Edite! @CristhianOrellanaMuñoz

Comment: Nop, nada....creo que no esta tomando el if..... pero no se por que....

Comment: Es que si no toma el if es porque el resultado esta fallando, tampoco te devuelve rows?? Imprimiste ese valor?

Comment: tal vez no lo estoy imprimiendo bien, lo hago asi echo $resultado_con; ? generalmente no imprimo los valores, solo reviso un buen rato mi código XD  PD: Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder

Comment: No, asi no... imprime el valor de $rows

Comment: Ahora si funcionaaaaaaaaaa.....gracias mil a  ti y a todos............ :D ahora  puedo continuar con lo demás.... tengo el examen mañana y solo me quedan algunas horas, pero alcanzo a terminar.... me habeis salvado la vida... T.T

Comment: Jajaja me alegro @CristhianOrellanaMuñoz , exito en ese examen!

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, has comprobado qué te devuelve la query? nunca te devolverá 0, devuelve un `object` o `false` si la consulta ha fracasado. debes recibir el resultado y tratar-lo para ver qué te ha devuelto, luego haz la comprobación por ejemplo de código producto.

```
if($resultado_con==0)
```

Answer (score 1):

La función `mysqli_query`, tal y como indica en la **[documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php)**, devuelve `false` en caso de no devolver nada. Por tanto, tendrías que cambiar tu if a:

```
if($resultado_con==false){
   //Código si es falso (si no hay registros)
}else{
  //Código si es verdadero (hay registros)
}
```

Comment: ya lo prove, pero no funciona...

Comment: @CristhianOrellanaMuñoz ¿Te da algún error? Prueba imprimiendo el valor de $resultado_con a ver que te devuelve.

Answer (score 0):

1) Aunque sea un proyecto de prueba, Evita que alguien te de un dolor de cabeza y perdidas de dinero escapando el input (aun si eres tu mismo quine lo genera).

[SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Acerca de la pregunta, por lo general me evito realizar la consulta para verificar si un item se encuentra en la base de datos utilizando lo que yo llamo un upsert. (Esto solo funciona si tienes claves primarias definidas por lo general lo utilizo con pk combinadas).

La query queda de esta manera:

```
INSERT INTO table (id_prod, id_suc, value1, value2, value3)
VALUES (1, 2, '1','2','3')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
table.value1 = VALUES(table.value1),
table.value2 = VALUES(table.value2);
```

De esta manera solo debes mantener una query, para este tipo de casos que maneja ambos, insert y update.

Si este forma de realizar las cosas no se adapta a tu estilo, como ya han dicho los demas debes cambiar tu validacion para que trabaje validando si el resultado devuelto por la consulta es false.

`if($resultado_con == false) { doSomething(); }`

Comment: Lo hice  pero no funciona.... nos se insertan los datos,,,,